# wpa supplicant - probing to AP before connect to check credentials

Tags: wireless-networking, debian, c++, wpa-supplicant, wpa2-psk

For recent development project I need to get the WIFi credentials from user end and submit to wpa_supplicant for initiate WiFI connectivity. I wrote a util using C++ which is doing the job but not the proper way. What my util doing is setup and try to initiate  the connection using given credentials. If it success no issue. If It fails I'm removing the configuration and waiting for valid credentials from the user. And as a support to this module I'm checking internet connectivity via respective interface on background whether it's up or now

Even though this method is work perfectly fine, I feel like it's not the proper way to do. I went through wpa_supplicant config (which is pretty long doc) but not able to find any solution. All I want to do is before configuring supplicant probing the AP and make sure credentials are correct. I know that this is not possible without full connection to the AP, but if there is a way to check it without configuring the supplicant that's enough

My setup running on debian stretch

Comment: Have a look at `wpa_cli` and the API of wpa_supplicant, which you can e.g. call from your C++ program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> All I want to do is before configuring supplicant probing the AP and make sure credentials are correct.

Use the following command to connect to an AP **without writing a configuration file**:

```
wpa_supplicant -i <Interface> -c(wpa_passphrase "Your-AP-here" Your-password-here)
```

Use `-B` option to run the command on background.

Use `grep` to filter the results or simply run `dhclient` to ensure that your are successfully connected.